# Reading text file, parsing it, and storing it into a hash

Tags: ruby

I want to open a text file name test.txt and turn into hash which has the condition value into 1111 only

```
Instance Id:xxxxx, value: 123
Instance Id:xxxxx, value: 1111
Instance Id:xxxxx, value: 1111
```

can any one please help me.

This my sample code:

```
File.open('test.txt').each_line do |line|
 puts line if line.match(/1111/)
end
```

Comment: `line.split` will probably be useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
# define a array in the outside scope so you can access it
array = []

# run your loop that reads the file
File.open('test.txt').each_line do |line|
  # split lines into two parts, instance_id - value pairs
  instance_id, value = line.split(',')
  # only add to array if the value is the one you're looking for
  # also, split instance_id to only get the value of the ID
  array << instance_id.split(':')[1] if value.match(/1111/)
end

puts array
# => ["xxxxx", "xxxxx"]
```

**EDIT**: updated the suggestion to better suit the updated request in the comments

Also worth noting is that it serves no purpose to have the values in a hash since you would have different IDs for the same value, you would want to put this in an array.

Comment: thanks @sergio Tulentsev. i want to get the output of the file when it matches value /1111/ i want to print the associated value of Instance id into file or hash